# webview in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios

I m passing an url as string from UIviewController to another uiviewcontroller..i was able to pass the url successfully but not able to load the string in the webview...in console i m getting a null value in webview could u guys help me out below is the code...

```
-(void)playAction1
{

    webviewcontroller *newEnterNameController = [[webviewcontroller alloc] initWithItem:@"http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=222"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];

    [newEnterNameController  release];      
}

- (id)initWithItem:(NSString *)url
{

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"webviewcontroller" bundle:nil]) 
    {
        self.title=@"facebook";

        self.url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

        //URL Requst Object
        self.requestObj1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
        NSURLConnection *connection=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.requestObj1 delegate:self]autorelease];

        [self.webViewAnnouncements loadRequest:self.requestObj1];
        NSLog(@"webView:%@",webViewAnnouncements);
        [self.webViewAnnouncements setDelegate:self];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: @kingston why are you creating a NSURLConnection?

Comment: @Damien:i m using that to check whether there is internet connection using KCFU...

Comment: @kingston: I would look at Apple's Reachability sample code to implement this reliably. One advantage of this approach is that you can notify the user as to current network status even the user isn't actually clicking on any links in the web view.

Comment: @kingston: while what you're doing doesn't look wrong to me (in truth I'd need to see .h and .xib files) as well to be sure. I would consider the initWithItem to be an unusual pattern. If I was you, I would init the view controller in the "normal" way using initWithNib and then create the URL as a property type and set it before you present the view controller to the screen.

Comment: @Damien:yeah this initWithitem is quite unusaul...i did the normal way instead of initWithItem..gave initWithnibname...coresponding nib name...instead of passing the data ,i used the Nsurl on the .m...works fine..thanks for ur intrest dude

Comment: So you're all fixed and ready to go?

Comment: cool... I might move my last comment out to an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you're doing doesn't look wrong to me (in truth I'd need to see .h and .xib files) as well to be sure. I would consider the initWithItem to be an unusual pattern.

If I was you, I would init the view controller in the "normal" way using initWithNib and then create the URL as a property type and set it before you present the view controller to the screen.